# ORA-01790 error on union; datatypes verified

Tags: oracle, ora-01790

I am joining 2 large queries (155 columns) in a `'union all'`. I have verified that the column names and datatypes are the same on each side of the union by creating test views of each query and comparing the names and datatypes side by side.

The error message points to a line and column that seems random, but I've checked those columns carefully to make sure that the datatypes `(varchar2(1300))`are the same.

Does anyone know what other factors may trigger this error? Running `Oracle 12c.`

Comment: As far as I remember, names are not important (the must be defined on first SELECT of the UNION, but the can be omitted or be different in the next one).  It's important that the two queries returns same number of column, and corrispondent data type is the same.

Comment: @etsa That is correct - e.g. this query is valid: `select empno, ename from emp union select deptno, dname from dept;`  So the problem must be with data types.

Comment: Understand that the names are not important, but wanted to show that the number of columns matched on both sides of the union. :)

Comment: Have you any CASE in your views?

Comment: @etsa: no CASE statements, but 1 decode() and several cast() statements.

Comment: could you post decode()?

Comment: Do you still get the same error if you union together queries against the two test views? What other debugging have you done - e.g. removing column expressions from both branches to identify the problem one? While doing that, can you create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem? Also, do the queries in either branch use database links?

Comment: @etsa: decode(i.uf_exte_comp, 'FOC','Full and Open Comp', 'NCS', 'NCS', 'FCA', 'Follow on', 'CUS', 'Competed Under SAP', 'FCE', 'FCE', 'NC', 'Not Competed', 'NAC', 'Not Avail for Compete', '') as uf_exte_comp

Comment: @pccdavef   It's seems to me "decode" is ok.  Have you tried what Alex P. suggested above (remove columns expressions one by one) and eventually reduce number of rows returned too, to identify the column(s)  which cause the problem?  It's a tediuos job, but sometimes it's the only way...

Answer (score 3):

Since you have already created those two test views, why not let oracle compare the column types?

```
SELECT column_id, data_type FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE table_name='MYVIEW1'
MINUS
SELECT column_id, data_type FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE table_name='MYVIEW2';
```

This should quickly point you to the conflicting columns. (Swap MYVIEW1 and MYVIEW2 if necessary)

Comment: Great idea. I tried this and the query above returned no rows. (Tried both ways as well).

Comment: Strange... no result here but `SELECT * FROM myview1 UNION SELECT * FROM myview2` causes the error 01790?

Comment: I'd say you use this query, as the one written above is not exhaustive: `SELECT 'MV1-MV2-1' as place, column_id, data_type FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE table_name='MYVIEW1'
MINUS
SELECT 'MV1-MV2-2' as place, column_id, data_type FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE table_name='MYVIEW2'
union all
SELECT 'MV2-MV1-3' as place, column_id, data_type FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE table_name='MYVIEW2'
MINUS
SELECT 'MV2-MV1-4' as place, column_id, data_type FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE table_name='MYVIEW1';`

Comment: @g00dy: you use different values for `place` in each part of the query, therefore, `minus` will not do anything ;-)

Comment: You're right - let that one splip out :) so the first two should go as '1' for example and the thrd and the fourth should go as '2'. That should do it :))

Comment: @erich - yes. I'm puzzled.

Comment: @g00dy: tried the query as corrected - no rows returned. Weirder and weirder.

Comment: @erich: yes, both of the queries in the union work independently.